# Error coming while performing OCR using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path.
```

I am using Pycharm Community and trying to install the tesseract for OCR.
My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

# Path of working folder on Disk
src_path = "C:/Users/fsipl/Desktop/"

def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    #  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    #img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

    # Remove template file
    #os.remove(temp)

    return result


print('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print(get_string(src_path+"word_text.jpg"))

print("------ Done -------")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you prepare a good question and potentially get right answer

Comment: 1. I have added the new environment variable too with the name tesseract

Comment: Installed the tesseract packages also through the help of pacman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got the problem solved with a single line change.

We have to provide the executable path of the pytesseract exe

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

## Here is the code below:

```
def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    #  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    # img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

    # Remove template file
    # os.remove(temp)

    return result
```